# onclick no toma la función

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando usar un onclick para guardar unos productos a una sección de favoritos pero llevo horas leyendo e intentando de todo y no consigo solucionarlo, a continuación les dejo el error que me arroja la consola al darle clic al botón de favoritos.

ERROR:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: add_to_favorites is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

Código:

```
    function load_products(section){
            page_section = section;
            let url = base + '/load/products/'+page_section+'?page='+page;
            http.open('GET', url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
            http.send();
            http.onreadystatechange = function (){
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                    page = page + 1;
                    let data = this.responseText;
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (data.data.length === 0){
                        load_more_products.style.display = "none"
                    }
                    data.data.forEach(function (product, index){
                        let div = "";
                        div += "<div class=\"product\">";
                        div += "<div class=\"image\">"
                        div += "<div class=\"overlay\">";
                        div += "<div class=\"btns\">";
                        div += "<a href=\""+base+"/product/"+product.id+"/"+product.slug+"\"><img src=\"img/mostrar.svg\" alt='imagen' width=\'20\' height=\'20\'></a>";
                        div += "<a href=\"\"><img src=\"img/carrito-de-compras.svg\" alt='imagen' width=\'20\' height=\'20\'></a>";
                        div += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"add_to_favorites('"+product.id+"', '1');\"><img src=\"img/lista-de-deseos.svg\" alt='imagen' width=\'20\' height=\'20\'></a>";
                        div += "</div>";
                        div += "</div>";
                        div += "<img src=\""+base+"/uploads/products/"+product.file_path+"/t_"+product.image+"\" alt='imagen de producto'>";
                        div += "</div>";
                        div += "<a href=\""+base+"/product/"+product.id+"/"+product.slug+"\">";
                        div += "<div class=\"title\">"+product.name+"<div>";
                        div += "<div class=\"price\">"+currency+""+product.price+"<div>";
                        div += "<div class=\"options\"><div>";
                        div += "</a>"
                        div += "</div>";
                        products_list.innerHTML += div;
                    });
                 }else{
                    //mensaje de error
                }
            }
        }
    
    
function add_to_favorites(object, module){
          url = base + '/favorites/add/'+object+'/'+module;
          http.open('POST', url, true);
          http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
          http.send();
          http.onreadystatechange = function ()
          {
           if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
           {
              let data = this.responseText;
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              console.log(data);
          }
      }
    }
```

No entiendo porque no me reconoce la función, la probé y esta bien, no entiendo el motivo del error, agradecido quien pueda darme alguna sugerencia de como solucionar este problema.

Comment: Las funciones *bindeadas* al DOM deben estar en un contexto global. En tu caso, `add_to_favorites` no está en ese contexto global, sinó en el contexto de `load_products`.

Comment: Desde el load la llamo mediante un onclick, mas no esta en el mismo bloque.

Comment: Debes fijarte des de dónde se invocará `add_to_favorites`. Aunque estés definiendo ese `onclick` en la función `load_products`, no está **invocando** la función  `add_to_favorites`. La invocación se dará **después** y des de otro contexto (el contexto de `global`).

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, podrías dejarme alguna documentación para leerla y entender tus palabras y gracias por responder. :D

Comment: JS no encuentra la función `add_to_favorites`, revisa que el archivo JS donde está declarada esta función, se esta llamando (`<script src="archivo.js">` tag) en el archivo html donde creas los elementos dinámicos. Imagino que tienes ambas funciones en el mismo archivo JS.

Comment: Así es, intente ponerlas en otro archivo y colocar primero load para después add y tampoco funciona :/

Comment: Ok, se me ocurre revisar si el script tag del html donde creas los divs, esta dentro de la etiqueta body.

Comment: eso lo use para despejar dudas, pero uso el mix de laravel y mis JS los tengo en un solo archivo app.js, pero vuelvo a recalcar que lo intente de la manera tradicional con el tag script en el html antes de cerrar el body 
```</footer>
<script src="{{ url('/js/app.js?v='.time()) }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

intente con un addEventListener pero no se como pasar los parámetros del product.id al AddEventListener ya que eso es un recorrido mediante el foreach de load.

Comment: Puede que la segunda respuesta sea de ayuda [mix larvel reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869707/laravel-mix-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Revise cuidadosamente lo que me dijiste y no, no es eso :/, la verdad estoy algo agnóstico con ese problema :/

Comment: Esta difícil, ya se propusieron todas las soluciones mas comunes, yo tomaría un respiro y me distraería un rato, mientras deberías editar la pregunta y mencionar que estas usando **laravel**, y porque no, agregar todo el `index.html` donde creas los divs, y cualquier otro archivo que consideres relevante, suerte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejo la solución, mi amigo Joaquin de MX me ayudo a resolverla.
Hicimos un querySelect el cual llamamos mediante una clase, luego accedimos al atributos y así logramos resolverlo, espero le sirva a alguien más :D

```
function load_products(section) {
    page_section = section;
    let url = base + '/load/products/' + page_section + '?page=' + page;
    http.open('GET', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
    http.send();
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            page = page + 1;
            let data = this.responseText;
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.data.length === 0) {
                load_more_products.style.display = "none"
            }
            data.data.forEach(function (product, index) {
                let div = "";
                div += "<div class=\"product\">";
                div += "<div class=\"image\">"
                div += "<div class=\"overlay\">";
                div += "<div class=\"btns\">";
                div += "<a href=\"" + base + "/product/" + product.id + "/" + product.slug + "\"><img src=\"img/mostrar.svg\" alt='imagen' width=\'20\' height=\'20\'></a>";
                div += "<a href=\"\"><img src=\"img/carrito-de-compras.svg\" alt='imagen' width=\'20\' height=\'20\'></a>";
                div += "<a class=\"js-item\" href=\"#\"  data-product-id=\'"+product.id+"\'><img src=\"img/lista-de-deseos.svg\" alt='imagen' width=\'20\' height=\'20\'></a>";
                div += "</div>";
                div += "</div>";
                div += "<img src=\"" + base + "/uploads/products/" + product.file_path + "/t_" + product.image + "\" alt='imagen de producto'>";
                div += "</div>";
                div += "<a href=\"" + base + "/product/" + product.id + "/" + product.slug + "\">";
                div += "<div class=\"title\">" + product.name + "<div>";
                div += "<div class=\"price\">" + currency + "" + product.price + "<div>";
                div += "<div class=\"options\"><div>";
                div += "</a>"
                div += "</div>";
                products_list.innerHTML += div;
            });
            $item = document.querySelectorAll(".js-item");
            $item.forEach(function(Item) {
              Item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let product = parseInt(Item.getAttribute('data-product-id'));
                add_to_favorites(product,1);
                
                });
            });
        }else{
            //mensaje de error
        }

    }
}


function add_to_favorites(object, module) {
    let url = base + '/favorites/add/' + object + '/' + module;
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
    http.send();
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            let data = this.responseText;
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Buenas, Niklaus.

Para que puedas entender mejor los conceptos de "scope", puedes leerlos en la documentación [Scope (MDN Web Docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Adicionalmente, como te comentaron los compañeros, el motivo por el cuál no puedes invocar la función `add_to_favorites`, se debe a que éste se encuentra inalcanzable para el elemento `HTMLAnchorElement` que estás creando. Si te fijas, la función está dentro de tu otra función, de esta forma, estás declarando la función en el ***contexto local (local scope)***,  y por lo tanto, es inaccesible desde afuera.

Para aclararlo un poco más, he creado un pequeño código basado en el tuyo:

```
<script>
    // Contexto Global

    function load_products() {
        // Contexto Local

        let div = "";
        div += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"add_to_favorites('0', '1');\">Stackoverflow</a>";
        document.getElementById("product_list").innerHTML = div;

        function add_to_favorites(object, module) {
            console.log("Agregado a favoritos!");
        }
    }

    load_products();
</script>
```

Al ejecutarlo, muestra el problema que tienes:

[image: Ejemplo 1]

Para solucionar esto, simplemente pasa la función `add_to_favorites` al contexto donde pueda ser 'alcanzable' por el elemento creado (en este caso, sería el **contexto global**):

```
<script>
    // Contexto Global

    function load_products() {
        // Contexto Local

        let div = "";
        div += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"add_to_favorites('0', '1');\">Stackoverflow</a>";
        document.getElementById("product_list").innerHTML = div;
    }

    function add_to_favorites(object, module) {
        console.log("Agregado a favoritos!");
    }

    load_products();
</script>
```

[image: Ejemplo 2]

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta describe el problema, en el ejemplo de @Niklaus ambas funciones `load_products` y `add_to_favorites`, tienen su propio scope.

Comment: Exacto, es lo que trato de decir pero parece que nadie me entiende, y como no soluciona mi problema, no puedo aceptar esta respuesta.

Son dos funciones separadas correctamente.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con 'separadas correctamente'? En el código que pusiste, una función está dentro de la otra, en ese caso el elemento `<a>` que estás creando en `load_products`, no encontrará la función `add_to_favorites` (porque está dentro de la otra, es decir, en el scope local de la función `load_products`).

Comment: Amigo si mete el codigo en un ide, se dara cuenta que esta separadas correctamente, :S

Comment: Por eso te pregunto, porque justamente lo hice pegando el código que brindaste en tu pregunta (a excepción que recorté el código, pero lo demás está igual)

Comment: Perdona! Ya miré la edición que hiciste, ahí sí está diferente